# Is it possible to bypass a broken google reCaptcha?

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

Theres a really old unmantained website that I want to login in order to delete some of my data. But the login implies a broken google reCaptcha that is out of date.

Is there anyway to bypass it?

```
<div class="blockrow">


<input id="hash" type="hidden" name="humanverify[hash]" value="406ce850ba1a84096f95dec36de5663e">

    <label for="recaptcha_challenge_field">Verificación de imagen</label><script type="text/javascript">
        var RecaptchaOptions = {
        theme : 'white',
        callback: function() {document.getElementById('recaptcha_response_field').tabIndex = 1;}
        ,lang : 'es'
    };
        function reloadRecaptcha(){
            if( typeof(Recaptcha) != 'undefined')
            {
                Recaptcha.create("6Ld0vssSAAAAAMtKWZYzqLf3nMSRUWk98uaTz9he", "recaptcha_block", RecaptchaOptions);
            }
        }
    </script>

<div id="recaptcha_block">


        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6Ld0vssSAAAAAMtKWZYzqLf3nMSRUWk98uaTz9he">

        </script>

</div>

<noscript>

        <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6Ld0vssSAAAAAMtKWZYzqLf3nMSRUWk98uaTz9he" height="300" width="400" frameborder="0"></iframe>

 <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40" tabindex="1"></textarea>
 <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge" />
</noscript>
```

The recaptcha is actually hidden

Comment: You might be able to bypass recaptcha on the client side, but not on the server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comment by Alon Eltan, it is possible on the client side, but not on the server side.
For real protection, reCaptcha creates a token server-side when you successfully pass the test.
And without the token, verification will fail.